# "Error:(1, 1) java: too many parameters" after adding javafx textfields

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, textfield

I have to add several hundred textfield to a GUI.

For that I add the javafx.scene.control.TextFields to a few different panes:

```
TextField txt1 = new TextField();
TextField txt2 = new TextField();
TxtPane.getChildren().addAll(txt1, txt2);
```

But after a certain number of Textfields, intelliJ is giving me the error above, is there some easy workaround or some "official way" to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: where is this error? If it's an exception, please provide full stack trace. If it's IDE error, please provide a screenshot. Also, note `addAll()` can take 254 parameters max by Java specification in case you are adding them all together.

Comment: Why are you even creating that many `TextField`s one by one? [DRY!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) There is most likely a way to reduce the amount of textfield creation expressions in your code and not add a huge number of fields using a single call to `addAll`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for the input. 
@Sergey no there was no stacktrace, the Error just showed up in the lower box. I used different panes to add the TextField's so i don't get why i got the error.

@fabian: You brought me on the right path. I use an TexField array now to create the TextField's and add them with .add():

```
    TextField[] someTextFields = new TextField[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        someTextFields[i] = field;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       somePane.getChildren().add(someTextFields[i]);
    }
```

It works for me now thanks again, since i can't vote for fabians answer i will mark my own if that is ok?